# is there is an option to combine different line in lists in loop in python code

Tags: python

I'm trying to calculate `impairment((NPV) - loan loss provisions)` on loan repayment on monthly basis.
I need to calculate each month's NPV and subtract it from the loan balance.
For that, I have a code that is working fine:

```py
res_list0 = []
for i in range(0, len(test_list)):
    res_list0.append(test_list1[i]/(1+rate/100)**(test_list[i]/12))
sllp = [test_list3[0] - sum(res_list0)]
```

sllp is loan loss provision for the first month.
Now I need to calculate sllp for the remaining 23 months where `res_list0` will be `res_list1`, ... until `res_list23`;

For me, the problem is to define months `(test_list[i]/12)` because it always must start from index 0, meaning 0/12

it should look like this when I'm going a long way

```py
res_list = []
for i in range(0, len(test_list)):
    res_list.append(test_list1[i]/(1+rate/100)**(test_list[i]/12))
sllp = [test_list3[0] - sum(res_list0)]

res_list2 = []
for i in range(1, len(test_list)):
    res_list2.append(test_list1[i]/(1+rate/100)**(test_list[i-1]/12))
sllp2 = [test_list3[0] - sum(res_list0)]

res_list3 = []
for i in range(2, len(test_list)):
    res_list3.append(test_list1[i]/(1+rate/100)**(test_list[i-2]/12))
sllp3 = [test_list3[0] - sum(res_list0)]

...

res_list23 = []
for i in range(23, len(test_list)):
    res_list23.append(test_list1[i]/(1+rate/100)**(test_list[i-23]/12))
sllp23 = [test_list3[0] - sum(res_list0)]
```

If you could help me combine this first code that provides SLLP for the first month with code that will provide a result for the remaining 23 months in list form.

[test_list = months; test_list1 = Monthly payments; test_list3 = Principal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzeJG.png)

[this is how it look like in excel calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8uf2.png)

Comment: Welcome! Can you edit your question to include a sample of your data (or fake data with the same structure)? It sounds like `test_list` or `test_list1` might be a 2d-array.

Comment: hi, thank you for your interest, i added link as image. test_list = months, test_list1 = Monthly_payments and test_list3 = Principal